# <inp>5__2 was null Exception in Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am receiving the error above. I am validating one field against another, basically after inputting the data into a text box, it is checked if it exists in another. I had set an if condition to ensure that if the data doesn't exist, then it returns to the same page for another try otherwise save. But the the error `<inp>5__2 was null.` is returned if the data doesn't exist.

Below is the code:

```
var inp = _ipacontext.Inpolicies.ToList().Where(x => x.PolicyNo == custView.Ppolicy).SingleOrDefault();
if (String.Equals(inp.PolicyNo, custView.Ppolicy))
{
custView.CID = Guid.NewGuid();
 _context.Add(customerData);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

return RedirectToAction("Complete", "Home");
}

return Redirect("/Home/Create");
```

`custview.policyNo` is the field entered from the form while `inp.PolicyNo` is the existing field being validated against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's no element in `_ipacontext` that meets the condition in your `Where`, [SingleOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-5.0) will return the default value (i.e., null for a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) like a user-defined class). So this line:

```
var inp = _ipacontext.Inpolicies.ToList().Where(x => x.PolicyNo == custView.Ppolicy).SingleOrDefault();
```

... Might leave you with a null `inp` variable. In the next line you're doing `inp.PolicyNo`, i.e., calling a getter on a potentially null instance.

You could use a [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) to safely access your property:

```
if (String.Equals(inp?.PolicyNo, custView.Ppolicy)) //Note the ? after inp
```

That way, if `inp` is `null`, `inp?.PolicyNo` will return null, and your `if` will translate to: `if(String.Equals(null, custView.Ppolicy))`, which is false.

As a sidenote, `String.Equals` could be replaced by simply using `==`. That way this wouldn't remind me of the legacy Java backend I have to maintain.

**EDIT.**

I just noticed that you're effectively doing the same comparison twice. Your piece of LINQ will return null if there's no matching element, so you could just do:

```
    var inp = _ipacontext.Inpolicies.ToList().Where(x => x.PolicyNo == custView.Ppolicy).SingleOrDefault();
    if (inp != null)
    {
      //Stuff
    }
```

Or even better clearer:

```
    if (_ipacontext.Inpolicies.Any(x => x.PolicyNo == custView.Ppolicy))
    {
      //Stuff
    }
```